# What is .foo(), .bar(), .baz() in python? as mentioned is below link

Tags: python

[Execute multiple python files using a single main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603482/execute-multiple-python-files-using-a-single-main)

As of the solution in the below link, what is foo baz and bar in python programming and why it is used for?

Comment: It's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212049/meaning-of-foo-bar-baz-etc). Technically, they are made up names. They're just calling/importing stuff from the files `one`, `two`, `three`.

Comment: TL;DR: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3092

Comment: It's just an example functions' name. Nothing specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a metasyntactic variable.**

These names are often used as example variables. On python, ham, eggs and spam are used too.
Wikepedia says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable